# qrcode.toImage - input text field for content showing Error: No input text in console

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using qrcode-with-logos to create a local html page that can generate QRCodes with a predefined logo. I've created a text input within the body of the HTML and I'm attempting to get the content option within QrCode to use what has been inserted in the text input however nothing is returning.

I've tried using toString() however it keeps returning blank. When I directly insert a value into content "https://www.google.com/" as an example, it works perfectly. The whole point is that I can paste in different URLs via the page and quickly get my QR codes. I've used the dist demo as a template and modified it so far to my needs.

```
  <body>
    <input id="text" type="text" placeholder="Enter text here">
      <button onclick="qrcode.toImage()">click me!</button>
    </p>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <img src="" alt="" id="image" />
    <script src="./qrcode-with-logos.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
        window.qrcode = new QrCodeWithLogo({
            canvas: document.getElementById("canvas"),
            content: text,
            width: 380,
            //   download: true,
            image: document.getElementById("image"),
            logo: {
                src: "data:image/png;base64,
                logoSize: 0.2
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I'm using qrcode-with-logos to create a local html page that can generate QRCodes with a predefined logo. I've created a text input within the body of the HTML and I'm attempting to get the content option within QrCode to use what has been inserted in the text input however nothing is returning.

I've tried using toString() however it keeps returning blank. When I directly insert a value into content "https://www.google.com/" as an example, it works perfectly. The whole point is that I can paste in different URLs via the page and quickly get my QR codes. I've used the dist demo as a template and modified it so far to my needs.

```
  <body>
    <input id="text" type="text" placeholder="Enter text here">
      <button onclick="qrcode.toImage()">click me!</button>
    </p>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <img src="" alt="" id="image" />
    <script src="./qrcode-with-logos.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
        window.qrcode = new QrCodeWithLogo({
            canvas: document.getElementById("canvas"),
            content: text,
            width: 380,
            //   download: true,
            image: document.getElementById("image"),
            logo: {
                src: "data:image/png;base64,
                logoSize: 0.2
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```